# QueryDSL regex Function not resolving

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

Good evening. I've been stuck on an issue and wanted to see if anyone here has some advice. I recentlu upgraded my Springboot version from 2.5.14 to 3.1.3 and now one of my queries in not working. I see that MetadataBuilderContributor was deprecated, but I did not use this package in my previous version. When I run my code I get the error:

*[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'regexp(ed1_0.friends,'\b110081\b')=1*

Does someone know why regex expressions are not resolving in QueryDSL? Please let me know if you guys see the issue in my code. Thank you in advance.

`Expressions.booleanTemplate("function('regexp', {0}, {1})=1", QUser.friends, REGEX_FORMAT.formatted(userId));`